# Wordpress change media upload directory

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, directory-structure

I manage to upload my medias using the below code. Unfortunately, the media are saving on the same month as the front-end form post date (/2014/09/). This is to upload the users profile image, not attached to any post. Hope someone can help out cause i couldnt find any resources online. Thank you!

```
        // UPLOAD USER IMAGE
            function upload_user_image($user, $nonce_name, $input_name, $field_name ) {
            if ( 
                isset( $_POST[$nonce_name] ) 
                && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[$nonce_name], $input_name )

            ) {


                $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($_FILES[$input_name]['name']));
                $uploaded_file_type = $arr_file_type['type'];
                $allowed_file_types = array('image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png');
                if(in_array($uploaded_file_type, $allowed_file_types)) {


                    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
                    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
                    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );


                    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( $input_name, 0 );

                    if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
                        $upload_feedback = 'There was a problem with your upload.';
                    } else {
                        $upload_feedback = false;
                    }
                    update_user_meta( $user, $field_name, $attachment_id );


                } else {
                    $upload_feedback = 'Please upload only image files (jpg, gif or png).';
                }



            } else {

                $upload_feedback = 'Security check failed';
            }
            }
```

Comment: Where do you want the images stored?

Comment: @rnevius Based on the current month. Currently, its saving in uploads/2014/09. It should be in /2014/10. Based on my online research, it is saving in such manner because its following the frontend form post date. I tried change the form publishing date to this month and then it saves /2014/10. Since this is not a post, thus i am having this issue. I am not sure how to incorporate the wp_handle_upload to change the directory path to follow the current time into the above code.

Comment: Have you tried passing an override into `media_handle_upload`? Something like: `$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( $input_name, 0, array(), array( 'time' => 'yyyy/mm' ));`

Comment: @rneviu Nope, didnt work. I know i have to add the wp_handle_upload  in somewhere. Trying to figure this out...